# recursive copying of filenames but not their content

Tags: copy

I want to recursively copy a directory (with sub-directories and files). This can be easily done using xcopy. But with regard to files, I only want their names (something "touch" could do in Linux) and not their content, the reason being the files are large and I am doing processing only on the filenames and not in their content. Any suggestions for a program/script for this task?

Comment: Why don't just read the tree structure and process it... ? What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot program. I have some scripting skill. I am trying to do this on Windows. With regard to processing the tree structure, is there some command in windows that reads a text file that has a list of files, goes on and creates those empty files with specific titles (Something like this could be easily done in Linux I guess? (Or any program working in Windows)

Comment: Sorry, this is a programmers site. Ask your question in http://superuser.com/

Comment: Can you please move the question to superuser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Gnuutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and `find -exec touch`?